# How to resolve WMQ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory error?

Tags: maven, queue, mule

Getting the below error while deploying the interface into Cloud Hub, In my local machine application got deployed successfully.

I need to poll data from WMQ. The error seems to related to that. My interface is maven based interface.

I have added all WMQ required jars to build path

[image: Build path Jar files]

My POM file look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.katalystm</groupId>
    <artifactId>apl-integration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-PRE</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule apl-integration Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <mule.version>3.8.5</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.1</mule.tools.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-objectstore</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-transport-sap</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    </inclusions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-wmq-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
            <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.conn.idoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>sapidoc3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-objectstore</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-sap</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
         <repository>
        <id>Central</id>
        <name>Central</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>codehaus-mule-repo</id>
        <name>codehaus-mule-repo</name>
        <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>  
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository> 
    <repository>
            <id>mule-ee-releases</id>
            <name>MuleEE Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

PFB error message getting while deploying to cloud.

```
null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:181)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader.findClass(MuleApplicationClassLoader.java:138)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:117)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.wmq.WebSphereMQConnector.<clinit>(WebSphereMQConnector.java:39)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:629)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:677)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:660)
    at org.mule.config.spring.parsers.assembly.DefaultBeanAssembler.methodExists(DefaultBeanAssembler.java:564)
    at org.mule.config.spring.parsers.assembly.DefaultBeanAssembler.bestGuessName(DefaultBeanAssembler.java:533)
    at org.mule.config.spring.parsers.assembly.DefaultBeanAssembler.extendBean(DefaultBeanAssembler.java:112)
    at org.mule.config.spring.parsers.AbstractMuleBeanDefinitionParser.processProperty(AbstractMuleBeanDefinitionParser.java:211)
    at org.mule.config.spring.parsers.AbstractMuleBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(AbstractMuleBeanDefinitionParser.java:422)
    at org.mule.config.spring.parsers.AbstractMuleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractMuleBeanDefinitionParser.java:297)
    at org.mule.config.spring.parsers.generic.MuleOrphanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(MuleOrphanDefinitionParser.java:38)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out below links these helped me

1. [Mule 3.4: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088348/mule-3-4-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-ibm-mq-jms-mqconnectionfactory)
2. [ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710138/classnotfoundexception-com-ibm-mq-jms-mqconnectionfactory-websphere-mq-7-5-s)

Let us knows if thats helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You added all related JARs to your local environment (your IDE build path), but said JARs are not packaged with your application, thus not available on CloudHub upon deployment and causing your error. As mentioned on the [CloudHub documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/developing-applications-for-cloudhub#packaging-third-party-libraries), you need to make sure your third party JARs are placed into the `/lib` folder of your app package.

I recommend you add all required JARs as Maven `<dependency>`, thus your JARs will be included in your Mule application archive `/lib` folder by Maven (you can then remove them from your IDE's classpath, they will be automatically added under M2_REPO/...). For example for `mqjms`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.07</version>
</dependency>
```

The tricky part is that most of your JARs (IBM libs) are proprietary and not available on Public Maven repositories. You may need to:

- Make sure they are available on your entreprise repo (if you have any) to allow you and your team members to use them. See [Guide to deploying 3rd party JARs to remote repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html). *(Note: I don't know licensing regarding these JARs, it may not allow such deployment)*
- If you do not have a private entreprise repo available, simply install these JARs on your local repository. See [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

You also have the possibility to add them manually or using another way, the important thing being that upon deployment on CloudHub these JARs are in the app `/lib` folder.